# C++ Child class inheriting parent class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an assignment that requires two classes to be derived from a base class. I am having issues getting the derived classes to call the base class constructor and successfully set the inherited variables. I recreated the issue with a dummy program for simplicity since the assignment is much longer.

```
#include <iostream>

class ParentClass {
    public:
            ParentClass(int theField1, int junk);
            ParentClass() {}
            virtual void printField();
            virtual void setField(int nf);

    protected:

            int field1;
};

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
    public:
            ChildClass(int theField1);
            void printField();
            void setField(int nf);
};

ParentClass::ParentClass(int theField1, int junk) {
    field1 = theField1;
}

ChildClass::ChildClass(int theField1) {
    ParentClass::ParentClass(theField1, 3);
}

void ParentClass::printField() {
    std::cout << "The field = " << field1 << std::endl;
}

void ChildClass::printField() {
    ParentClass::printField();
    std::cout << "Some other stuff." << std::endl;
}

void ParentClass::setField(int nf) {
    field1 = nf;
}

void ChildClass::setField(int nf) {
    ParentClass::setField(nf);
}

int main() {
    ChildClass* myChild = new ChildClass(777);
    ChildClass child2(888);
    myChild->printField();
    child2.printField();

    myChild->setField(10);

    myChild->printField();

    child2.setField(20);
    child2.printField();

    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives me the following output:

```
The field = 0
Some other stuff.
The field = 4197296
Some other stuff.
The field = 10
Some other stuff.
The field = 20
Some other stuff.
```

Why do the first two attempts not work? Calling the constructor should be initializing the variables to the value passed as a parameter, but they are not actually set until I specifically call a mutator function. I tried a third class which used the parent mutator function in its constructor rather than the parent constructor:

```
class StepChild : public ParentClass {
    public:
            StepChild(int nf);
};

StepChild::StepChild(int nf) {
    ParentClass::setField(nf);
}
```

The object as defined in main:

```
    StepChild* step = new StepChild(30);
    step->printField();
```

The output:

```
The field = 30
```

Where am I going wrong that attempting to use the parent constructor is not properly initializing these variables?

I also tried changing the parent class to be not virtual, and it worked as well, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the parent class.

Comment: How you are trying to accomplish this `ParentClass::setField(nf);`??

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but that was just a test to see if I could construct a derived class using the setField function. All it does is set the variable field1 equal to the parameter.

Comment: Find an example of how to initialize a base class in a derived class. This pops up in all inheritance tutorials and chapters of books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [initialiser lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
ParentClass::ParentClass(int theField1, int junk)
  : field1(theField1)
{ }

ChildClass::ChildClass(int theField1)
  : ParentClass(theField1, 3)
{ }
```

The following - from your code - creates a temporary ParentClass object and throws it away - that has no affect on the ChildClass object under construction:

```
 ParentClass::ParentClass(theField1, 3);   // temporary
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the parameters match, you can also do it the c++11 way by putting

```
using ParentClass::ParentClass( int, int );
```

in your ChildClass class definition. It is the same as invoking the parent constructor from the ChildClass constructor initialiser list, but a little less esoteric.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I find something wrong in the way you are calling base class constructor.

[try this way to call base class constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/26837/) and see if the problem is solved.